# MySql error 1118 (Row size too large) on update

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have the following MySql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `realizations` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `place` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and I'm trying to update a row using the following query:

```
UPDATE realizations SET id="new-id", place="Some place", image="image.jpg" WHERE id="some-id"
```

but I get the following error:

```
> #1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

But none of my fields exceeds column limit (255 characters). 
I've tried to reduce the query to a simple `id` update

```
UPDATE realizations SET id="new-id" WHERE id="some-id"
```

but I get the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: Please add `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`.

Comment: Older version need a bunch of work to change the log_file_size.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which you can do:

1. You can try to change the `innodb_log_file_size` in the `my.ini` text file. The reason has been mentioned in [Changes in MySQL 5.6.20 (2014-07-31)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-20.html)

> **Important Change:** Redo log writes for large, externally stored BLOB
>   fields could overwrite the most recent checkpoint. The 5.6.20 patch
>   limits the size of redo log BLOB writes to 10% of the redo log file
>   size. The 5.7.5 patch addresses the bug without imposing a limitation.
>   For MySQL 5.5, the bug remains a known limitation.
>
> As a result of the redo log BLOB write limit introduced for MySQL 5.6,
>   the innodb_log_file_size setting should be 10 times larger than the
>   largest BLOB data size found in the rows of your tables plus the
>   length of other variable length fields (VARCHAR, VARBINARY, and TEXT
>   type fields). No action is required if your innodb_log_file_size
>   setting is already sufficiently large or your tables contain no BLOB
>   data.

2. You can refer the solution given in [InnoDB create table error: “Row size too large”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/innodb-create-table-error-row-size-too-large)
3. Also a good read: [14.8.7 Limits on InnoDB Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/innodb-restrictions.html)